# Error during the initialization of the SDK! DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, microblink, blinkid

First of all, my project uses node 14.17.0.
I'm using BlinkID in browser SDK version 5.14.0. I get the following error:

Error during the initialization of the SDK! DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://yourdomain.test/advanced/BlinkIDWasmSDK.js' failed to load.

I'm using the same as the docs

```
import * as BlinkIDSDK from "@microblink/blinkid-in-browser-sdk";

mounted(){
  this.initializeBlinkIDSdk()
}
methods(){
  initializeBlinkIDSdk(){
     if ( BlinkIDSDK.isBrowserSupported() )
        {
            const loadSettings = new BlinkIDSDK.WasmSDKLoadSettings( "your-base64-license-key" );

            BlinkIDSDK.loadWasmModule( loadSettings ).then
            (
                ( wasmSDK) =>
                {
                    // The SDK was initialized successfully, save the wasmSDK for future use
                },
                ( error ) =>
                {
                    // Error happened during the initialization of the SDK
                    console.log( "Error during the initialization of the SDK!", error );
                }
            )
        }
        else
        {
            console.log( "This browser is not supported by the SDK!" );
        }

  }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason you're using such an old version? v6.1 was released very recently and if API differences are a problem you can try v5.20.
Regarding the error, seems like a badly configured engineLocation, you can find more details in the docs: https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-in-browser#-configuration-of-sdk

Comment: to confirm you're actually hosting the resources properly you can directly go to http://yourdomain.test/advanced/BlinkIDWasmSDK.js and see if it's there

Comment: Thanks. You're right, it was a badly configured engineLocation, didn't read the instructions properly, had to host the resources folder in my public files. Also, I'm using that version not bc I want to, but because it is my job's main website, it uses and old version of node and there's little I can do to upgrade it. As I'm not the dev in charge, but just one more from the team

Comment: Glad to help! I'll double-check the node version requirements but off the top I'm pretty sure you can run a newer version of the BlinkID SDK with the node version you're currently using.
Feel free to shoot an email to support@microblink.com, we can look into your setup to confirm the above and provide new keys if necessary :D